# function that obtains a list and returns a new one with the data without repeating the first list

Tags: python, list, function

function that obtains a list and returns a new one with the data without repeating the first list. The order doesn't matter. In python

Comment: Can you give an example to clarify what you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

order the list randomly?

```
from random import sample

your_list = range(1, 100)

new_list = sample(your_list, len(your_list))

print(new_list)
```

your list is ordered randomly